# HTTPS site not being captured by BURP

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, burp-suite

I am testing a website, basically mapping the site using burpsuite. But there is one link(https) that I can not process while the proxy on firefox is enabled. It asks me for certificates and when I ensure that I understand the risks and click on "add exception" the "confirm exception" icon doesnt seem to work,it just stays there. And Thus I can't seem to visit the link using burp.

I know it's a noobish question but the fact is that I am stuck here. Please guide me.

Comment: Burp has a very clever solution for this: http://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_installingcacert.html

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you add your Burp certificate to your trusted certificates list. This can be done by loading Burp, proxying a browser through it, and then visiting http://burp/. You should see a page which has a few links across the top, one of which is "CA Certificate". Clicking this will give you a download of a file called "cacert.der".

You can then install this either for a specific browser, or for the whole system - I suggest using a specific browser or browser profile for Burp, but it's up to the individual user. For Firefox, the certificate can be installed by going to Options->Advanced->View Certificates, then "import". For Windows, double clicking the certificate will allow you to install it. There is also an automatic configuration tool for Firefox called "Plug-n-hack", available from the same Burp loaded page, which automatically installs the certificate and configures the proxy settings.